# R: table formatting

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an excel file with the following columns

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
ab        bb        0.5
ab        bc        0.1  
ab        cd        0.7
ab        dd        0.8
ac        bb        0.2
ac        bg        0.8
ac        ee        0.8
ac        dd        0.3


x <- data.frame (column1 = c("ab","ab","ab","ab","ac","ac","ac","ac"), 
                 column2 = c("bb","bc","cd","dd","bb","bg","ee","dd"),
                 column3 = c(0.5, 0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.3))
```

I want to change it do.

```
    ab   ac
bb  0.5  0.2
bc  0.1  
cd  0.7
dd  0.8  0.3
bg       0.8
ee       0.8
```

Answer (score 3):

The `reshape2` package is your friend here:

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(x, column2 ~ column1, value.var="column3")
#   column2  ab  ac
# 1      bb 0.5 0.2
# 2      bc 0.1  NA
# 3      bg  NA 0.8
# 4      cd 0.7  NA
# 5      dd 0.8 0.3
# 6      ee  NA 0.8
```

## Update

Since @jmsigner and I have posted virtually exactly the same answer at the same time, here's an option in base R, but that doesn't give you as nice of an output:

```
reshape(x, direction="wide", idvar="column2", timevar="column1")
#   column2 column3.ab column3.ac
# 1      bb        0.5        0.2
# 2      bc        0.1         NA
# 3      cd        0.7         NA
# 4      dd        0.8        0.3
# 6      bg         NA        0.8
# 7      ee         NA        0.8
```

Comment: +1 for base solution and for using '_is your friend_' in your opening line.

Comment: @thelatemail, ah, but DWin's base solution is so much nicer. For some reason, most of the time that I see a question like "I want to change this to that", and the problem is about wrangling with columns and rows, one of the variants of `reshape` pops into my mind before `xtable`. But, I'll still gladly accept your upvote for the "is your friend" part!

Answer (score 3):

```
xtabs(column3 ~ column2+column1, data=x, sparse=TRUE)
6 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
    ab  ac
bb 0.5 0.2
bc 0.1 .  
bg .   0.8
cd 0.7 .  
dd 0.8 0.3
ee .   0.8
```

If you do not use the 'sparse' argument, there will be zeroes in the missing categories. You could replace them with `is.na<-

```
xt <-  xtabs(column3 ~ column2+column1, data=x) 
is.na(xt) <- xt==0
xt
       column1
column2  ab  ac
     bb 0.5 0.2
     bc 0.1    
     bg     0.8
     cd 0.7    
     dd 0.8 0.3
     ee     0.8
```

Comment: I always forget about `xtabs` for this type of problem, though I think it is probably the best in this case. (+1)