# Automate division in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is the current manual solution that I have. I was wondering how I would implement an automated solution to my problem.

`smarties <- aggregate(Mention_DRGU ~ USC5_CLASS + AGE + year  , data = chanko , sum )`

```
keto <- filter(smarties, AGE == "0-2" & year == "2010")[,4]/Actual$ZERO.TWO[1]
keto1 <- filter(smarties, AGE == "0-2" & year == "2011")[,4]/Actual$ZERO.TWO[2]
keto2 <- filter(smarties, AGE == "0-2" & year == "2012")[,4]/Actual$ZERO.TWO[3]
keto3 <- filter(smarties, AGE == "0-2" & year == "2013")[,4]/Actual$ZERO.TWO[4]
blarg <- matrix(c(keto,keto1, keto2,keto3), nrow=9, ncol = 1)
cbind(filter(smarties, AGE == "0-2")[,1:3],blarg)
```

I've been reading other users questions which are similar to mine, and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016577/looping-some-simple-division) and I have tried to implement, but I'm hung up on using the `tapply function.

Basically if the Age and Year are similar I want it to divide from the appropriate column in my Actual data.frame.

```
temp <- split(smarties, f = list(smarties$AGE, smarties$year))
```

`dput(Actual)`

```
    structure(list(Region = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada"
), Year = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"), Level = c("ID", 
"PD", "PR", "PP"), Sex = c("3", "3", "3", "3"), Total = c(34005, 
34343, 34754, 35158), X0.2 = c(1139, 1139, 1140, 1145), X3.10 = c(2900, 
2935, 2980, 3024), X11.19 = c(3835, 3792, 3740, 3684), X20.39 = c(9247, 
9325, 9474, 9618), X40.59 = c(10106, 10150, 10185, 10197), X60.64 = c(1982, 
2050, 2071, 2110), X65. = c(4736, 4887, 5099, 5310)), .Names = c("Region", 
"Year", "Level", "Sex", "Total", "X0.2", "X3.10", "X11.19", "X20.39", 
"X40.59", "X60.64", "X65."), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

`dput(smarties)`

```
structure(list(USC5_CLASS = structure(c(5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 5L, 
8L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
12L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 
6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 
2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 12L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("15111 TETRACYCLINE", "15112 TETRACYCLINE CONGENERS", 
"15130 CEPHALOSPORIN", "15141 ERYTHROMYCIN", "15142 EXTENDED SPEC MACROLIDES", 
"15152 AMOXICILLIN", "15153 OTHER BRD SPEC PENICILL", "15180 TRIMETHOPRIM COMBS", 
"15190 BRD/MED SPEC OTHER", "15210 PENICILLIN V & VK", "15230 ANTI-STAPH PENICILLIN", 
"15810 QUINOLONES, ORAL"), class = "factor"), AGE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L), .Label = c("0-2", "3-9", "10-19", "20-39", "40-59", "60-64", 
"65+", "UNSP"), class = "factor"), year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L), Mention_DRGU = c(5760L, 
19230L, 5610L, 4700L, 36660L, 16070L, 7600L, 32910L, 39850L, 
2230L, 5690L, 49240L, 214790L, 144420L, 27840L, 60320L, 5520L, 
98940L, 216040L, 103030L, 27440L, 10840L, 5500L, 145650L, 5610L, 
44470L, 16510L, 7910L, 2470L, 38280L, 5520L, 61050L, 22340L, 
10390L, 28960L, 5460L, 5460L, 22380L, 2470L, 5980L, 5550L, 11370L, 
23830L, 5840L, 5590L, 14680L, 68290L, 47860L, 2110L, 73700L, 
1960L, 177290L, 177440L, 47750L, 103110L, 16650L, 57340L, 5530L, 
214590L, 143790L, 50590L, 3280L, 5680L, 104760L, 28860L, 47150L, 
5550L, 28680L, 5680L, 10970L, 5590L, 50260L, 28380L, 11480L, 
28800L, 2260L, 7820L, 13750L, 11120L, 14700L, 16840L, 55900L, 
11060L, 5680L, 39920L, 166720L, 156230L, 19990L, 5540L, 60910L, 
5540L, 10960L, 16780L, 205220L, 153830L, 30970L, 3500L, 110530L, 
5540L, 50360L, 44410L, 18140L, 16760L, 5400L, 11080L, 39180L, 
31650L, 16840L, 5530L, 55590L, 1390L, 5860L, 2100L, 2100L, 28660L, 
15460L, 5770L, 22890L, 56150L, 5540L, 17010L, 45740L, 114940L, 
224230L, 37560L, 5670L, 60150L, 11310L, 39620L, 162890L, 178530L, 
57780L, 74110L, 16900L, 15500L, 16850L, 17090L, 5610L, 14490L, 
17020L, 11350L, 45100L, 5700L, 17100L, 11340L, 5670L)), .Names = c("USC5_CLASS", 
"AGE", "year", "Mention_DRGU"), row.names = c(NA, -146L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think it would be easier if you set this up differently. You're just making it hard on yourself trying to match `0-2` variable and `ZERO.TWO` column name. Also you have a column called `THREE.TEN` but your corresponding variable is `3-9`. then what is `FIFTY.THREE` and what does `UNSPEC` and `65+` map to?

Comment: @rawr 65+ corresponds to FIXTY.THREE (sorry I'm not sure why I choose it); I plan on ignoring UNSPEC values for this

Comment: @BenBolker I've been trying `sweep` but I've been unsuccessful. From experimenting with it, I now know that I should use the data.frame which I applied `split` to because then it doesn't have dims, but then how do I select Year and Age from the smarties.

Comment: I'd highly recommend that you learn about [tidy data](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/) and adopt a consistent convention for how you store variables.

Comment: @hadley you're right, a lot of problems seem to stem from my data not being tidy, do you know of other resources besides your journal article that are helpful for getting acquainted with tidy data (specifically the tidyr package)

Comment: There's also the vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not solid programming, but it appears to work:

```
# remove rows not to be analyzed
smarties <- smarties[smarties$AGE != 'UNSP', ]

# get row and column indices
smarties$agenum <- as.numeric(smarties$AGE)
smarties$colnum <- smarties$agenum + 5
smarties$yearnum <- as.numeric(as.factor(smarties$year))

# send col and row index (x and y) to find denominator from Actual df,
# and numerator z
smarties$result <- mapply(FUN = function(x,y,z,df){
  z/df[x,y]
},x = smarties$yearnum,y = smarties$colnum,z = smarties$Mention_DRGU,MoreArgs = list(df = Actual))
```

It depends on the age and year coming up in the correct order, as well as the columns staying where they are in the correct order.

**Update**

This won't break as easily because it uses names. You can use whichever *apply makes sense to you.

```
# remove rows not to be analyzed
smarties <- smarties[smarties$AGE != 'UNSP', ]

# rename variable names and fix weird names
smarties$agecol <- paste0('X',gsub(pattern = '\\-|\\+',replacement = '.',x = smarties$AGE))
smarties[smarties$agecol == 'X3.9','agecol'] <- 'X3.10'
smarties[smarties$agecol == 'X10.19','agecol'] <- 'X11.19'

# mapply
smarties$mresult <- mapply(FUN = function(x,y,z,df){
  z/df[df$Year == x,names(df) == y]
},x = smarties$year,y = smarties$agecol,z = smarties$Mention_DRGU,MoreArgs = list(df = Actual))

# or apply
smarties$appresult <- apply(smarties,1,function(x,df){
  as.numeric(x['Mention_DRGU'])/df[df$Year == x['year'],names(df) == x['agecol']]
},df = Actual)
```

**Update 2**
This is a better way to go by changing the data to a consistent format.

Fix up the dataset:

```
# tidy data aka wide to long format
require(tidyr)
smarties <- smarties[smarties$AGE != 'UNSP', ]
Actual <- gather(Actual,age,secretvalue,-c(Region,Year,Sex,Level,Total))

# fix age mismatches (should actual type them in)
Actual$age <- levels(smarties$AGE)[as.numeric(Actual$age)]

# make names in both datasets the same
names(Actual) <- tolower(names(Actual))
names(smarties) <- tolower(names(smarties))
```

After restructuring the data, the solution is simple

```
# merge appropriate data since it is 1:1
smartiesmerged <- merge(smarties,Actual[ ,c('year','age','secretvalue')],by = c('year','age'),all.x = T)

# do the calculation
smartiesmerged$result <- smartiesmerged$mention_drgu / smartiesmerged$secretvalue
```

Comment: Hey Andrew, your code is perfect. I just wanted to ask something (but it didn't require creating a new post) how would I add another variable to match to (like was done with agecol). I have a column in both my smarties and Actual dataset now that represents region.

Comment: For the first update, you'll have to feed in the region data everywhere there is an agecol. Restructuring your data like in Update 2 (reference hadley's comment) makes maintenance like adding variables trivial. You would add 'region' in both of the c()'s in the merge function and that's it.

Comment: Ooh that's is such an easy way to approach this problem. Thanks! I had actually taken hadley's advice and had tidied my data before your suggestion so it was incredibly easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a somewhat less manual way of doing it with `dplyr`.

```
blarb <- melt(Actual)

Lol <- filter(blarb, variable == "X0.2", Year == "2010")
smarties %>%
  filter(AGE == "0-2", year == 2010) %>%
  mutate(Popul = Mention_DRGU/Lol$value)
```

Unfortunately I still have to do it for every Age and Year, does anybody know if I could use the group_by to further automate this?